# Add icon to Text field in Label control

Tags: asp.net

I want to know if there is a way I can add an icon to asp.net Label's Text.

So, something like

```
<asp:Label run="server"
Text= "Please see the "icon" below />
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't use the `text` property this way - the `Text` string will terminate with the `"` before the word `icon`.

However, any HTML markup will **not** be escaped, so you can use an `<img>` tag.

```
<asp:Label run="server"
   Text="Please see the <img src='icon.gif' /> below" />
```

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.label.text.aspx) (Label.Text):

> The Text property can include HTML. If it does, the HTML will be passed unchanged to the browser, where is might be interpreted as markup and not as text.

Alternatively, you can add an `asp:image` to your markup, or place one *between* two `Label` controls.

Comment: This can screw up sizing and positioning of elements on the page so I wouldn't go overboard but it works just fine for small images like a trademark logo, etc.

Answer (score 0):

No. There is not a property such as icon or image in asp label. Here is the syntax and options available in asp.net label

```
<asp:Label
    AccessKey="string"
    AssociatedControlID="string"
    BackColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderColor="color name|#dddddd"
    BorderStyle="NotSet|None|Dotted|Dashed|Solid|Double|Groove|Ridge|
        Inset|Outset"
    BorderWidth="size"
    CssClass="string"
    Enabled="True|False"
    EnableTheming="True|False"
    EnableViewState="True|False"
    Font-Bold="True|False"
    Font-Italic="True|False"
    Font-Names="string"
    Font-Overline="True|False"
    Font-Size="string|Smaller|Larger|XX-Small|X-Small|Small|Medium|
        Large|X-Large|XX-Large"
    Font-Strikeout="True|False"
    Font-Underline="True|False"
    ForeColor="color name|#dddddd"
    Height="size"
    ID="string"
    OnDataBinding="DataBinding event handler"
    OnDisposed="Disposed event handler"
    OnInit="Init event handler"
    OnLoad="Load event handler"
    OnPreRender="PreRender event handler"
    OnUnload="Unload event handler"
    runat="server"
    SkinID="string"
    Style="string"
    TabIndex="integer"
    Text="string"
    ToolTip="string"
    Visible="True|False"
    Width="size"
/>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct way.

However you can use simple HTML `<label>` tag with `for="id"` attribute attached to `ImageButton` for instance

```
<asp:ImageButton ID="ToggleButton" runat="server" ImageUrl="~/images/expand.gif" onclick="ToggleButton_Click" />
<label ID="ToggleButtonLabel" for="ToggleButton" runat="server">Range Summary</label>
```